# Name for plane perpendicular to a vector

Tags: terminology

In writing some vector processing requirements, I want to use the correct terminology. For a 3D vector defined between the origin and a point, is there a term or name for a plane that is perpendicular to that vector? Are there any special names, such as for the plane satisfying this condition and also going through the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the vector $\mathbf{n}$, say. Then you could refer to the plane as a "normal plane to $\mathbf{n}$", or "normal plane to $\mathbf{n}$ through $O$" if you wish to specify the location of the plane relative to the origin as in your post.

Comment: This is what I'll use as an explanation and just create my own short hand if I need to refer to more than one or to several.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the plane/vector "perpendicular" to another vector is common and perfectly acceptable. Also common is the word "normal" (e.g. "the vector $(1, -1, 1)$ is normal to the plane $x - y + z = 3$.")

Comment: I'm just looking for something that is a little less wordy, if it exists. I have to refer to this with respect to several different vectors and their projections onto the corresponding planes, and it would be helpful to have a pre-existing term (if there is one).